# Two identically distributed sequences of random variables, but different in the view of convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm looking for an example of two sequences of random variables  ${X_n} $'s  and $X'_n $'s, such that ${X_n} $'s converges to  $X $ , almost every where , but $X'_n $'s converges almost sure to  no random variable and 
these sequences have the same distribution.

How is it possible?

Is there any hint? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

1. For a suitable distribution $\mu$ (for instance uniform distribution on $(0,1)$) find two random variables $X,Y$ which have both distribution $\mu$ and which satisfy $\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|>\epsilon)>0$ for some $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small.
2. Consider the sequences $$X_n := X \qquad \quad Y_n := \begin{cases} X, & \text{$n$ is odd}, \\ Y, & \text{$n$ is even}. \end{cases}$$ Show that $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$ and that $Y_n$ does **not** converge almost surely.

Comment: if $Y_n $ is convergent a.a,so we have to have $X=Y $ almost every where. But why it is wrong?

Comment: @user115608 I don't get your question. I said that $Y_n$ is **not** convergent.

Comment: ok i know.i'm trying to prove it by contradiction.assume it is convergent,then...

Comment: @user115608 If it was convergent, then $X=Y$ almost surely (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|>\epsilon)=0$ for all $\epsilon>0$) in contradicton to our assumption that $\mathbb{P}(|X-Y|>\epsilon)>0$ for small $\epsilon>0$.